# Unable to push master to git

Tags: git

I'm following the instructions at [Ubuntu Git Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git)

Success fully installed the git-core and gitosis packages on the server A

```
A# sudo apt-get -y install git-core gitosis
A# gitosis user's password is gitflux
```

Initialized gitosis with

```
A# sudo -H -u gitosis gitosis-init < ~/keys/git-dsa-public2.key
```

Now checkout the gitosis-admin branch on local machine

```
B$ git clone gitosis@A:repositories/gitosis-admin.git
```

Tried to add a new project to the repository by editing the gitosis.conf

```
[gitosis]

[group team]
writable = sweepshots
members = git_id_rsa

[group gitosis-admin]
writable = gitosis-admin
members = git_id_rsa
```

and commit it back to the server. [there was no errors, but I'm not sure this worked correctly]

`A#cat /srv/gitosis/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/gitosis.conf`

is now showing

```
[gitosis]

[group team]
writable = sweepshots
members = git_id_rsa

[group gitosis-admin]
writable = gitosis-admin
members = git_id_rsa
```

Committing to the first project

```
 C$ mkdir sweepshots
 C$ cd sweepshots
 C$ git init
 C$ touch a_text_file.txt
 C$ git add .
 C$ git commit -a -m "Initial import"
 C$ git remote add origin gitosis@A:sweepshots.git
```

(also tried `git remote add origin gitosis@A:repositories/sweepshots.git`)

```
 C$ git push origin master
```

Here I'm getting the error

```
fatal: 'sweepshots.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Am I missing anything ?

-- UPDATE here is the directory listing at server A

```
root@testserver:~# cd /srv/gitosis/
root@testserver:/srv/gitosis# ls
git  gitosis  repositories
root@testserver:/srv/gitosis# ls gitosis
projects.list
root@testserver:/srv/gitosis# ls repositories/
gitosis-admin.git
root@testserver:/srv/gitosis# ls git
gitosis-admin.git
root@testserver:/srv/gitosis#
```

Comment: I guess you have to create a repository on the server first.

Comment: @ZeissS am i missing that? like how?

Comment: Can you confirm that the repository exists in the repositories directory?

Comment: @Ikke please see the update in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have a `sweepshots.git` repository on your server, so there is no repository git can push to. you have to create one first:

```
su gitosis # make sure the repository has the correct permissions
mkdir /srv/gitosis/sweepshots.git
cd /srv/gitosis/sweepshots.git
git init --bare
```

Comment: or just `git init --bare /srv/gitosis/sweepshots.git`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might need a `repo` section as shown on this webpage: http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt:gitosis_management#adding_a_new_repository.

```
[repo sweepshots]
description = My sweepshots project.
owner = John Smith

[group sweepshots]
writable = sweepshots
members = git_id_rsa
```